# How do I translate and scale at the same time? Or how do I enlarge and move an element at the same time?

Tags: svg

I have an SVG object that looks something like this

```
<svg>
  <g id="target-element"><path>...</path></g>
</svg>
```

I want to enlarge the `g` element and move it at once. I guess this means somehow applying `tranform="translate()"` and `transform="scale()"` at the same time in the `g` tag.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, all I had to do was `<g id="target-element" transform="translate(...) scale(...)"><path>...</path></g>`